# Resize Matrix upwards and left with Eigen Library

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm trying to resize my matrix with what we could say are negative indices, meaning they should be left and upwards from the origin (0,0) of that matrix. I've tried with grid.resize(-20,-20) but it does not work.

Any ideas are useful. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of indices I have a feeling of what you mean (see NumPy), but in terms of resize I really don't get what you mean here? It is a size, it can only be positive (or potentially some alias for I don't know for this axis, derive it from the total size)

Comment: Yes, the size should be positive, I was just expressing the need that the initial matrix stayed in the lower right corner, for I intend to resize it upwards and left.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible by default, as it involves resizing and then moving existing items to the end. If you really need this operation, you could do this yourself easily.

Comment: Yes, it's probably easier to make a new matrix with the desired size, copy the original matrix to the lower-right corner of the new one and delete the original matrix.

Comment: `grid.resize(-20,-20)` should assert (if compiled without `-DNDEBUG`). And `resize` will not keep the original content, if at all, `conservativeResize` would have worked (but this will always keep the original in the top-left corner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in-place anyway, so just create a new (sufficiently large) matrix, copy the original matrix to the bigger matrix and move/swap the matrices. Example implementation (could be generalized for LeftDown/RightUp/... -- also this implementation assumes that `up` and `left` are non-negative):

```
template<class Derived>
void resizeUpLeft(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& mat, Eigen::Index up, Eigen::Index left)
{
    typename Derived::PlainObject biggerMat(mat.rows()+up, mat.cols()+left);
    // Note: biggerMat will be filled with uninitialized values,
    // use setZero, if that is not desired
    // if allocation of biggerMat fails mat stays unchanged
    biggerMat.bottomRightCorner(mat.rows(), mat.cols()) = mat;
    // move or swap to avoid copy:
    mat.derived() = std::move(biggerMat);
    // with C++03:
    // mat.derived().swap(biggerMat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for